# Basic docker file

Tags: docker

I'm trying to learn docker.  I've installed docker and created a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM scratch
RUN echo 'hello world'
```

I thought the next step was to build and run the image, like this:

```
docker build mytestdir
```

But when I do, I get this error:

```
 => ERROR [1/1] RUN echo 'hello world'                                                                                       
 ------
  > [1/1] RUN echo 'hello world':
  #3 0.351 container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
```

What I'm trying to do is be able to print "hello world" when I run the container - just so that I can see the container is running. What am I missing / misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scratch` base image is empty (quite empty), it does not provide even a base SO. That is why there is no echo command inside it.

For your learning purposes, you can use [ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu), [centos](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos), [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) ...

Try the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN echo 'hello world'
```

But I think you want the image to print `hello world` when started, so you need to use [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run), not `RUN`. So change your Dockerfile to the following

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD ["echo","hello world"]
```

`RUN` will only echo your string when building the image, not when running the container.

Comment: Thanks - are you able to point me to a resource that tells me exactly what is available in the scratch image, please?

Comment: scratch image contains nothing at all. It is empty. There is no SO. Just an empty file system. Some links can be `https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages` or `https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch`